# Styled component doesnt't want to render on screen

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Like the title says, I have a problem with styled components. They do not want to render no matter what style attributes I add to them; they simply don't want to render. Does anyone know if I made a typo or something like that? This is the code I am working with.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const testStyled = styled.h1`
font-size:10px;
 `;

export const Datepicker = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <testStyled>Test</testStyled>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now this is how I am importing it into another component:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {Datepicker} from "./Datepicker"


export const AnotherComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Datepicker></Datepicker>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that React components must start with a capital letter, even if they are styled components. You can read more about it [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics) or [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/573).

Your code should be like this

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const TestStyled = styled.h1`
font-size:10px;
 `;

export const Datepicker = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TestStyled>Test</TestStyled>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React components use PascalCase: change `testStyled` to `TestStyled`.

```
const TestStyled = styled.h1`
font-size:10px;
 `;

export const Datepicker = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TestStyled>Test</TestStyled>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now.